# how to compile Qt with /Zc:wchar_t?

Tags: c++, qt, compilation, nmake

I'd like to compile Qt with /Zc:wchar_t set to Yes. This how I intend to compile it:

> configure -debug-and-release -opensource -platform win32-msvc2010
>
> nmake

I assume I have to change some kind of make file, but I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like to make such changes, you could edit the `qmake.conf` file for your particular platform. It will most likely be located in the `mkspecs\win32-msvc2010` directory within your Qt directory.